# "an unknown error occurred, please check the server response when uploading video" from uiimagepickercontroller to firebasestorage (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to upload video that user chooses (through uiimagepickercontroller), to Firebase storage, but I'm getting this strange error within my `localizedDescription`

> an unknown error occurred, please check the server response

Here's my code:

```
func uploadVideo(videoURL: URL)
    {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let videoRef = storageRef.child("rPosts/\(uid!)/\(fileID)")

        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "video/quicktime"
        
        videoRef.putFile(from: videoURL, metadata: metadata)
        { (metaData, error) in
            guard error == nil else
            {
                self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                //error happens here :(
                return
            }
            print("works")
        }
    }
```

Here is where it's used:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
    {
        if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL
        {
            uploadVideo(videoURL: url)
            uploadedYet = true
        }
        
        videoPickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'videoURL' come from?  How do you know that you still have access to your video clip without using a security-scoped bookmark?

Comment: What? `videoURL` is the parameter for my function `uploadVideo`. I do have access to the video clip because after downloading the URL, it prints out the correct URL.

Comment: While there is an accepted answer, there's a bit of ambiguity in the code in the question which may be involved in it not working. For example what does this `.child("rPosts/\(uid!)/\(fileID)")` resolve to? Is videoURL valid?

Comment: It creates a unique filepath so I can access it later

Comment: lol. Yes. But my question is what does it *resolve* to?e.g. what string is it?  Is it a valid path? When responding in comments preface the users name with an at sign so they will be notified of your reply. Like @Jay.

Comment: @Jay It's of type `StorageReference` but its filepath is a String. I'm literally creating a path, so it has to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebase's `putData:` method to Upload your Data,

Try it this way:

```
  func uploadVideo(videoURL: URL)
    {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let videoRef = storageRef.child("rPosts/\(uid!)/\(fileID)")
        
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "video/quicktime"
        
        var videoData : Data = Data()
        
        do
        {
            videoData = try Data(contentsOf: videoURL)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        videoRef.putData(videoData, metadata: metadata) { (metaData, error) in
            guard error == nil else
            {
                self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
                //error happens here :(
                return
            }
            print("works")
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup, don't know why, but this method works in place of `.putFile`, thanks!

Comment: Because Firebase's uploader doesn't have the correct permissions to access that file somehow due to the iOS App Sandbox, thus getting the file wouldn't work.

Comment: @EAO123 This is a great answer but there are a few things to consider. `putData` takes an generic Data object in memory and uploads it. One issue is the file needs to be loaded into memory to be converted to Data which can cause memory issues with very large files. It's also slower because its two steps (convert then upload) instead of just one. Also, the files become generic 'data' objects and have to be converted again when downloaded, which can be slower and lead to memory issues. putFile on the other hand maintains the file type, any size is ok, doesn't require conversion and is faster.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, it is really slow, I'm going to see if phpickerviewcontroller will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Firebase Storage settings, I changed settings with ;

```
 rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

And fixed it .